# Uglify JS Webpack plugin for Webpack Stream (Gulp + Webpack)

Tags: javascript, webpack, gulp, uglifyjs

I am trying to use Gulp + Webpack [workflow](https://webpack.js.org/guides/integrations/#gulp)

Most Things are working at https://github.com/IamManchanda/gulp-webpack/

But when I am trying to Implement [UglifyjsWebpackPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/) as per the mentioned docs, it just doesn't seem to work. I don't get any errors, what I get is simply the non-uglified code!

Here is my code for same => https://github.com/IamManchanda/gulp-webpack/pull/7/

In fact to be more specific, here is my [`config.production.js`](https://github.com/IamManchanda/gulp-webpack/blob/ac0b37fd1c45f7f3f8ba52dfc4b7680a73637339/webpack/config.production.js)

```
const UglifyjsWebpackPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
  devtool: 'source-map',
  output: {
    filename: 'scripts.js',
  },
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [
      new UglifyjsWebpackPlugin({
        sourceMap: true,
      }),
    ],
  },
};
```

Am I missing something? Do I need some more RTFM? Can you guys help me here
Let me know if you need any other details. Thanks in Advance.

**Edit:** Here is the video demo of the same issue: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Xa1E3vnXR2_fFuqZ8b5Hu4-kMb2gD2FT/view

Comment: everything is on, what is wrong?

Comment: Wait let me show a quick video @PlayMa256

Comment: is ok*, misspelled it.

Comment: @PlayMa256 I have added the video demo of the issue above, please have a look now :)

Answer (score 0):

Please change output filename to `scripts.min.js`, and use property `compress` as `true`.

```
const UglifyjsWebpackPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
  devtool: 'source-map',
  output: {
    filename: 'scripts.min.js',
  },
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [
      new UglifyjsWebpackPlugin({
        sourceMap: true,
        minify(file, sourceMap) {
        // https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2#minify-options
        const uglifyJsOptions = { /* your `uglify-js` package options */ };

        if (sourceMap) {
          uglifyJsOptions.sourceMap = {
            content: sourceMap,
          };
        }

        return require('uglify-js').minify(file, uglifyJsOptions);
       }
      }),
    ],
  },
};
```

Comment: Thanks bro for help but doesn't seem to work :(
Added the screenshot of error in Facebook DevC (from where you came here)

Comment: Alright, I can't test it on my enviroment, sorry about that. But I have updated the code according to documentation. Can you try this?

Comment: Please visit the URL in the code to see desired options before running the code.

Comment: Sorry for late reply... was in middle of something... Nopes updated the code ... Doesn't seem to work https://i.imgur.com/EKGREPr.jpg

Comment: By the way, here is the code for same that I added based on your comment what I understood https://github.com/IamManchanda/gulp-webpack/compare/minify-js-vohrahul

Comment: In the code, you have not passed in any option to compress. Also the file name is still scripts.js. I see you found another workaround, but as far as I can see, your code doesn't implement all the changes suggested in my answer. Also, please mark a correct answer for the question to help future readers. (Even if your answer is correct according to you. Mark it as correct).

Comment: Ohk buddy ... Will have a look ... Currently out but will do

Answer (score 0):

So as I needed this on urgent basis, I have used gulp to do the job instead of webpack ... That being said ... still looking for webpack solution

Anyways here is my Gulp based (gulpfile.js) Solution => https://github.com/IamManchanda/gulp-webpack/pull/8

1.

```
yarn add --dev gulp-uglify
```

2.

```
const gulpUglify = require('gulp-uglify');
```

3.

```
...((mode === 'production') ? [gulpUglify()] : []),
```

[image]

**I think what matters for me right now is that this works for me :)**

Answer (score 0):

Just define

`new UglifyjsWebpackPlugin` in `plugins`

```js
{
  'plugins': [
    new UglifyJsPlugin({
      'sourceMap': false,
      'parallel': true
    })
  ]
}
```

Don't use `optimization.minimizer`